Created Todo: Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated
Anchor code
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(todo_index: u8)] // Added this to pass the index as an instruction argument
pub struct CreateTodo<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [USER_TAG, authority.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        has_one = authority,
    )]
    pub user_profile: Box<Account<'info, UserProfile>>,

    #[account(
        init,
        payer = authority,
        seeds = [TODO_TAG, authority.key().as_ref(), &[todo_index as u8]], // Updated to use todo_index argument
        bump,
        space = 8 + std::mem::size_of::<TodoAccount>()
    )]
    pub todo_account: Box<Account<'info, TodoAccount>>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

Typescript client
  it("Created Todo", async () => {
    let user_profile_account = await program.account.userProfile.fetch(userPDA);
    console.log(user_profile_account);

    let [todoPDA, _bump] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [
        utf8.encode("TODO_ACCOUNT"),
        provider.wallet.publicKey.toBuffer(),
        Uint8Array.from([user_profile_account.currentTodoIndex]),
      ],
      program.programId
    );

    let content_todo = "My name is pranaya raj";

    let trxHash = await program.methods
      .createTodo(content_todo)
      .accounts({
        authority: provider.wallet.publicKey,
        todoAccount: todoPDA,
        userProfile: userPDA,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      })
      .rpc();

    let { content, idx, markedBool } = await program.account.todoAccount.fetch(
      todoPDA
    );

    expect(content).to.equal(content_todo);
    expect(idx).to.equal(user_profile_account.currentTodoIndex);
    expect(markedBool).to.equal(false);
  });


yarn run v1.22.22
$ /Users/pranayraj/Desktop/SolanaDoc/todo_dapp/node_modules/.bin/ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 'tests/**/*.ts'
The authority wallet addres is 12r4uFpQHVvVfX3qpAxHhddExdGMecFSZYPcVhxRPZNm
The PDA for creating User Profile is: ACcqx7Rk7zDLUb2rQsnQZaWKKvAPhyANxQJm7S3U9nGv
(node:4369) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)


  todo_dapp
Creating User Profile Account.......
    ✔ Initialized User Profile Account! (459ms)
The TodoPDA is: 2CQsCEpUXaDMGS9oZfgbzCY1cuXzNpNsBkFyYkj6ZQcz
    1) Created Todo
    ✔ Marked Todo
    ✔ Removed Todo


  3 passing (492ms)
  1 failing

  1) todo_dapp
       Created Todo:
     Error: AnchorError caused by account: todo_account. Error Code: ConstraintSeeds. Error Number: 2006. Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated.
Program log: Left:
Program log: 2CQsCEpUXaDMGS9oZfgbzCY1cuXzNpNsBkFyYkj6ZQcz
Program log: Right:
Program log: 7cHCMir3jWC3dcgqW1MV9tf2bhpHT7pTvTFNQ6Ka5Y2C
      at Function.parse (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/error.ts:168:14)
      at translateError (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/error.ts:277:35)
      at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:35:29)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)



error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.


could you share the full error logs.

I have shared it please check sir.  and also please check my github repo https://github.com/baindlapranayraj/Todo-dapp
